# I am trying to solve it but not solved, "time data ' Sept 26 2022' does not match format ' %b %d %Y'"

Tags: python, datetime, web-scraping, strptime

Here is the article link and code. https://www.nbcnews.com/business/travel/biden-administration-propose-new-rules-airline-fees-requiring-transpar-rcna49416

```
published_Date = soup.find('time', class_="relative z-1").get_text(strip=True).split(", ")
Published_Date = ""
published_Date = published_Date[0:2]
for i in published_Date:
    Published_Date += " " + i
Published_Date = Published_Date.replace(',',"").replace('.',"")
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(Published_Date, ' %b %d %Y')
Published_Date = datetime_obj.`enter code here`date()
print("\nPublished Date: ", Published_Date )
```

Comment: `%b` expects `Sep` not `Sept`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that date with:

```
published_Date = soup.select_one('time[class="relative z-1"]').get('datetime').split('T')[0]
```

Documentation for BeautifulSoup is quite good: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I have one more issue related to scrape date from website like this one there I am facing the splitting issue where .split('.', "") not working to scrape only date from this p tag <p class="text-xs">Oct 24, 2017 • 4 min read</p>
Published_Date = soup.select_one('p[class="text-xs"]').get('datetime')

Comment: There is no such element on that page you confirmed in your original question.@InfoRewind